# SimpleLazyObject' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

Team, I have tried to create a form for new posts, with following fields. Title, Body, Category. I need to have the author name (here called Owner) saved automatically with username used at login time, but although I was able to do this with date and time, I was not with user, Could you please help ? Please put more detail as you can

View:

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.datposted = datetime.datetime.now()
            post.owner = request.user()
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Favor. Verifique os campos necessarios")

    else:
        form = CreatePostForm()
        f = {'form' : form}
        return render(request,'create_post.html',f)
```

Models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    datposted = models.DateTimeField('date posted')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)


    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Logout(User):
    force_logout_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Entire error:'SimpleLazyObject' object is not callable

Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/newpost/
Django Version:  1.7.4
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

'SimpleLazyObject' object is not callable

Exception Location:  C:\Users\Documents\Treinamentos\Python\projects\projeto_blog\blogapp\views.py in create_post, line 176
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:  2.7.9
Python Path:  

['C:\\Users\\Documents\\Treinamentos\\Python\\projects\\projeto_blog',

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call the user object.

```
post.owner = request.user
```

Comment: How should I reference to the user then to save this information on database ?

Comment: Note in Daniel's answer the user object don't have a pair of parentheses as the code snippet you posted.

Comment: Sorry had not noticed that. I did this way as Daniel suggested and got this:


Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/newpost/
Django Version:  1.7.4
Exception Type:  ValueError
Exception Value:  

Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: marlm>>": "Post.owner" must be a "UserProfile" instance.

Exception Location:  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py in __set__, line 597

Comment: So what is your difficulty in interpreting that error message? You do indeed have the relationship going to UserProfile rather than User, so you need to use the appropriate object.